# Does a pension entitle you to health care in that (EU) country if you are visiting?

Tags: sweden

I am UK resident and spend time in Sweden. I have the EHIC card so I know I am covered for emergency healthcare there. However, I am applying for a visa to extend my time, and they require health insurance, and the EHIC card does not cover you for 'repatriation'. I have a Swedish pension and I know I can't ask for an SI form from the UK because Sweden would be responsible for my health care costs if I moved there. But does this also apply to when I visit?

EDIT:

> I have an EHIC, as it was issued before Brexit. However, I don't see it would materially change anything if it was the GHIC. In the UK the government website says you cannot apply for an SI form to cover you in an EU country where you are already receiving a pension. This is my situation in Sweden, where I receive a very small pension because I once lived there.

Comment: Unless you were resident in an EU country before Brexit and continue to be resident there, I don't think you have an EHIC.  The post Brexit replacement is the GHIC.  (It's worth being precise in these things).

Comment: Why can't you ask for an S1 if you are moving to Sweden?  We moved to Germany some time ago, and once my partner started drawing their state pension they applied for, and got, the S1.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, Yes I have an EHIC, as it was issued before Brexit. However, I don't see it would materially change anything if it was the GHIC.
In the UK the government website says you cannot apply for an SI form to cover you in an EU country where you are already receiving a pension. This is my situation in Sweden, where I receive a very small pension because I once lived there.